# How to loop through txt file and assign values to dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I have a part of API with dictionary:

```
    params = {
    'query': 'www.test.com',  # string for get info
    'se': 'g_it',  # string search engine
    'token': 'ad868fb77d43cfa57bc',  # string personal token
}
```

where query value is a domain name defined manually, I would like instead loop through lines in domains.txt file and assign query value from there:

```
['https://www.domain1.com']
['https://domain2.org']
['https://domain3.com.br']
```

In the result I should have:

```
params = {
        'query': 'https://www.domain1.com',  # string for get info
        'se': 'g_it',  # string search engine
        'token': 'ad868fb77d43cfa57bc',  # string personal token
    }


params = {
        'query': 'https://domain2.org',  # string for get info
        'se': 'g_it',  # string search engine
        'token': 'ad868fb77d43cfa57bce',  # string personal token
    }
```

etc.

I have tried:

```
mydomains = []
with open("domains.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        mydomains.append(line)

for item in mydomains:
    params = {
        'query': item,
                 'no.com',  # string for get info
        'se': 'g_it',  # string search engine
        'token': 'ad868fb77d43cfa57bc',  # string personal token
}
```

but that did not work

Comment: that will overwrite `params` on each loop iteration

Comment: Please make a [mre]. I think this is a simpler problem than you think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you should read your domains file:

```
mydomains = []
with open('requirements.txt', 'r') as f:
    mydomains = f.read().split('\n')
```

Once you've read your domains file, here's what the loop should look like:

```
params = []
for item in mydomains:
    params.append({
        'query': item,  # string for get info
        'se': 'g_it',  # string search engine
        'token': 'ad868fb77d43cfa57bc',  # string personal token
        })
print(params)
```

Output:

```
[{'query': 'https://www.domain1.com', 'se': 'g_it', 'token': 'ad868fb77d43cfa57bc'}, {'query': 'https://domain2.org', 'se': 'g_it', 'token': 'ad868fb77d43cfa57bc'}, {'query': 'https://domain3.com.br', 'se': 'g_it', 'token': 'ad868fb77d43cfa57bc'}]
```

Comment: Thanks, that works, I get first params as {'query': "['https://www.domain1.com']\n", 'se': 'g_it', 'token': 'ad868fb77d43cfa57bc'}, is there a way to get {'query': 'www.domain1.com', 'se': 'g_it', 'token': 'ad868fb77d43cfa57bc'} instead?

Comment: updated the answer. that's how you should be reading your text file to get the correct format.

Answer (score 0):

You need a list of dictionaries.
You are defining params dict inside the for loop which means that it's keys' values will be always overwritten by the last item that is being traversed in the loop. You should append this to a list defined outside the loop. And also, your token value in params shouldn't change with respect to each domain - as mentioned in your desired output